# Automatically convert a structure to single variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, global

I added all my variables, both **double** and **cell**, to a structure `V`, to avoid having `global` variables. To do it automatically I did this, which I found on the Mathworks forum :

```
varList = who;
V = struct;
for index = 1:numel(varList)
V.(varList{index}) = eval(varList{index});
end
```

Now I got into my model, and I don't want to add `V.` every single time a parameter is used, so I was thinking, is there a similar way (and is it convenient) to automatically reconvert everything back into variables?

Thank you!

**Edit:** I tried the solution proposed by ThP, with the modification of using `length` instead of `number`. It now works, but it prints out ALL the values every time. Since it goes into a function `MODEL` that is called multiple times, this is unfeasible. I tried just using the field names in `MODEL` but it is actually much slower. I guess I'll keep my global variables, unless you can suggest something that could work for me!

Comment: Check `fieldnames`, `struct2cell`, `structfun`. A combination of these would probably do. You need to use `eval` in a similar way as you do in the forward direction

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Luis, you can do it by using `filenames` and `eval`:

```
f = fieldnames(V);
for index = 1:number(f)
  eval([f{index} ' = V.' f{index}]);
end
```

Comment: That helps, but it stops because some values are cells and not numbers.I actually deleted the cell variables (because I don't really need them right now) but I keep getting the same error. Even when V in the workspace does not show the cells!

Comment: `Undefined function 'number' for input arguments of type
'cell'.`
When I check the workspace though, the structure V only has `double` and sparse matrices.

Comment: Where did you get the `number` function? I looked into the help and it is not defined.